# Heroku config:push not updating environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables, heroku-toolbelt

I've deployed an app to Heroku, and I'm currently storing my environment variables in an .env file. I used `heroku config:push` to push the variables up to heroku, and that worked fine.

Now, I want to update one of them. I changed it in my .env file, and ran `heroku config:push` again. The push said it was successful, but when I run `heroku config`, I can see that the values actually haven't changed. I've tried running `heroku restart`, but that didn't do anything.

How can I update my environment variables in heroku?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Figured it out. You need to run `heroku config:push --overwrite` because it won't overwrite existing variables by default. This is poorly documented :-/

Comment: +1 for poor documentation by heroku. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#local-setup clearly states that you need to use --overwrite when pulling variables but not when pushing.

Comment: `heroku config:push --overwrite` doesn't seem to be working for me. It still shows the older configuration when I do `heroku config`

Comment: It worked for me. But I noticed problems with spaces or quotes in the definition of my variables in .env. It seems you should not use any spaces or quotes, which makes it very hard to read

Comment: @morgler I also found out single quotes are different than double quotes.

Comment: is this still true today ?