# heroku config:push not adding environment variables

Tags: node.js, heroku, foreman

Hi I have done the following from the [heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

```
 heroku plugins:install git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-config.git
 heroku config:push --overwrite
```

my `.env` file is in root of project directory

```
GOOGLE_RETURN_URL = http://example.herokuapp.com/auth/google/return
GOOGLE_REALM = http://example.herokuapp.com/
```

I also set the --overwrite flag as [this answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016273/heroku-configpush-not-updating-environment-variables)

however when I echo my `heroku config` it remains empty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the spaces in your .env file.  Remove the spaces on either side of your "=" and the plugin will work.

Change:

```
GOOGLE_RETURN_URL = http://example.herokuapp.com/auth/google/return
GOOGLE_REALM = http://example.herokuapp.com/
```

To:

```
GOOGLE_RETURN_URL=http://example.herokuapp.com/auth/google/return
GOOGLE_REALM=http://example.herokuapp.com/
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `bash` doesn't let you do this either:

`$ FOO = "bar"
bash: FOO: command not found`